# Chrome inspector does not show network requests path and etc

Tags: google-chrome, inspector

I use AJAX and want to visit its behaivour while sending request to server through `Chrome Inspector`. When I switch to `Network` tab of inspector, requests not listing there.

[image: example]

---

Edit

`Inspector` is open and `network` tab is active, now I'll do something to trigger ajax request, but no report in inspector. I mean the situation is fully ready for inspector to show results, but some configuration should be changed.

Comment: Did the AJAX request happen before or after you switched to the Network tab? The network tab only records activity that happens after you bring it up.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan thanks for answer, yes inspector is open and network tab is active, now I'll do something to trigger ajax request, but no report in inspector

Comment: Can you confirm that your instance of Chrome doesn't return anything in the Network tab from this page: http://jsfiddle.net/clickthelink/Uwcuz/1/

Comment: @IrvinLim thanks for answer, again as my screenshot just show it's diagram and status bar at bottom of page. But no result or report for the path, status, domain and etc.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

As I said some configuration changed. All I need to do is click on `filter` icon (it's active when it's color is blue).
And then select the type of request I want to see. Default option is to select `All` or just to visit xhr request, select `xhr`.

[image]

Comment: The problem with filter's is that they are active all the time. Disabling the filter icon will just hide the filtering bar and nothing else.

Comment: Yes and we need it to change file type requested

Comment: my filter icon is always red even after clicking on it. Any other option to make it blue?

Comment: @Kurkula sorry I saw this late but for future users, in the newer version of Google Chrome, it seems the filter icon is red always. But no difference. If the filter is active you'll see a nav bar above request list

Comment: in the picture above XHR is selected, please select ALL to see all the requests

Comment: Oh, that is so dumb...  I've been using Chrome for years, and suddenly, this had a Filter set to JS (which I never use).   What the hell ?!!!    Thanks for the tip, much appreciated.

Comment: it works fine..

Comment: This is definitely very unrecognizable. Prolly 'FILTER ICON' that we use today is not good enough.

Answer (score 179):

Just a simple trick if any one of the above solutions doesn't work, then follow the steps below

1: Go to inspect tab aka developer tools.

2: Click on setting icon as show below, or by using the keyboard shortcut "Shift-?"

[image: 2: click on setting as show below]

3: Preference -> Click on **Restore default and reload** button see the image for reference

[image: 3: Preference -> Restore default see the image for reference]

Comment: It just works, simple and elegant. I already tried other solutions but somehow requests/responses were invisible.

Answer (score 32):

Be sure that there is nothing in the **Filter** field.

[image]

Comment: Had a space here... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 18):

[image]

As showed in the screenshots above

1. 1.press 'F12 key' and go network menu and check if your Has blocked cookies is checked or not
2. if checked and then uncheck it and refresh using F5.

I hope this might helps you....

Answer (score 15):

[image: screenshots]
As showed in the screenshots sequence above

1. press 'F12 key' and go network menu click on 'Filter Icon'
2. uncheck *"Only show requests with SameSite issues"* checkbox
3. reload chrome browser by pressing 'F5 Key'

Comment: Thanks, it's kinda confusing because that filter icon does not visually change when toggling the bar.

Answer (score 9):

hello i was trying to develop a form page with php and ajax and i faced the same problem. The filter input box above looked 0.5 by default. When I cleared the filter input box the problem was resolved and I could see the requests.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I had mistakenly typed some character in the filter search box. CLearing the filter box worked fine.

Comment: This was my issue.  Clearing out the filter box also made the filter icon turn blue (the desired color).

Answer (score 8):

1. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> and go to network menu click on 'Filter Icon'
2. See if any among "Hide data URLs" , "Has blocked cookies" and "Blocked Requests" is checked, uncheck it.
3. reload chrome browser by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>

Answer (score 8):

In my case, i typed something in filter box and forgot about it, it remained there even after restarting pc several times, had to remove it to see all the network requests again.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Next to the filter box, there is an option to check/uncheck "Hide data URLs". If it is selected, filter would appear RED.

Answer (score 2):

In my case for Chromium, the solutions was to tick the "Preserve log" checkbox in the filter toolbar. 
The error I am hunting for is of 404 HTTP-code type and Chromium hides the log line, then reloads and shows the Chromium default error page, along with filling the log pane with lines about loading the some data-url images.

Answer (score 2):

For users using modern javascript libraries such as React JS, Please check the Fetch/XHR tab. I've attached a picture for you to look over.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue where the time filter was unable to get earlier events. I think this is because the width of the waterfall dragger was obscuring the filter.

An easy workaround is to download the HAR file (see the down arrow) and then open a new tab and then re-upload. Cleared all of those annoying filters and I was able to see those early network calls again.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this issue and I resolved it by following the below steps:

1: Go to inspect tab, aka developer tools.

2: Click on "Settings" icon as show below, or by using the keyboard shortcut "Shift-?":

[image: Settings]

3: Preference -> Click on "Restore default and reload" button, see the image for reference:

[image: Restore default and reload]

Answer (score 1):

If the filter icon is red. Click the icon then select "all" in the filtering bar.
You will only see js files. Refresh your url and you will see all the files.

The icon will also turn blue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, nothing was present in the Filters box, but the JS option was selected.

Selecting the 'All' option will start showing all the requests.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also, check if the option "All" is selected or you are checking for a specific type for select multiple types next to Filter box

Answer (score 0):

[image: find word in filter search bar]

This can be one of the case,
I entered <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to find some word on screen but it had searched in dev-tool search bar and listed only calls that had searched phrase in it.Clearing search filter in dev tool helped in my case.
note: the filer is persistent even if you open new window or even tab.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me by select "All" in the developers tool page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and what I did was go to [setings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2wAC.png).

On preferences, you'll see Network then you can tweak the settings.

For me, I just [turned on the "Preserve log" and "Record network log"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jk5H.png).